# MongoDB find all document in A collection which has no relation to B collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB 3.4.15, I want to find all documents from the `Rating` collection where the ***resultid*** is not in the `Result` collection.

let's say that there is only one document in each collection

**Rating collection**

```json
     {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6255818aaaaa7f47c79eba01"),
            "_class" : "rating",
            "ratingid" : "b6885038-17ef-437c-b9c8-be7336a09744",
            "value" : 5,
            "components" : [
                {
                    "resultid" : "2285e41f-ebe4-4372-8cf8-64dfe91a9733"
                },
                {
                    "resultid" : "69053352-d933-46a0-a20c-3863e01b87d6"
                }
            ]
        }
```

**Result collection**

```json
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("62558188aaaa7f47c79eb9ff"),
        "_class" : "normal_results",
        "resultid" : "2285e41f-ebe4-4372-8cf8-64dfe91a9733",
        "totalTime" : Double("10"),
        "lastModified" : NumberLong("1649770887268"),
        "creationDate" : NumberLong("1649770887268"),
    }
```

In this case, the `Rating` collection's document should be returned, because `"resultid" : "69053352-d933-46a0-a20c-3863e01b87d6"` is not into `Result` collection.

Please help me to write the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply perform the `$lookup` and compare whether the `$size` of the lookup result is equal to `$size` of `components` array.

In Mongo v3.4, you can do below:

```js
db.Rating.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Result",
      "localField": "components.resultid",
      "foreignField": "resultid",
      "as": "resultLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dedupeComponents": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$components",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$in": [
                  "$$this.resultid",
                  "$$value"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$value",
              "else": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this.resultid"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "resultLookup": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$resultLookup",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$in": [
                  "$$this.resultid",
                  "$$value"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$value",
              "else": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this.resultid"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      matched: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: "$dedupeComponents"
          },
          {
            $size: "$resultLookup"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      matched: false
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      // cosmetics
      matched: false,
      dedupeComponents: false,
      resultLookup: false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2_YBUyA4Q2B) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks ray, but there is a problem. even if you change "resultid": "69053352-d933-46a0-a20c-3863e01b87d6" with the 2285e41f-ebe4-4372-8cf8-64dfe91a9733, it still retunes that document.

Comment: @jiboOne That's a valid point. I have added an `$addFields` stage to perform deduplication before the matching to cater to this scenario. Thanks for the feedback and please see if it's good to go now.

Comment: Now it works, thank you! one more question, how to add some restriction on creationDate? in real collections there is approximately 10000000 record in each and query timeouts, I want to add criteria to search this kind of documents only in certain period (Rating record also have the creationDate property, I just took it off to simplify).

Comment: @jiboOne you can put 1) a $match at the start of the aggregation to filter on `Rating` first 2) use `$and` to add another filter in the `$cond` inside `$reduce` to do this.